# What is the optimal way to implement a small cache in C# to store factorial values?

Tags: c#, caching, factorial

Here's the code I have:

===========================

```
public class Foo
{
    //Class field to store factorial values as those are calculated
    private static Dictionary<uint, double> _factorialCache;

    public Foo()
    {
        _factorialCache = new Dictionary<uint, double>();
    }

    public double Factorial(uint inputValue)
    {
        if (inputValue < 2) return 1;

        if (_factorialCache.ContainsKey(inputValue))
            return _factorialCache[inputValue];

        _factorialCache.Add(inputValue, (double)inputValue * Factorial(inputValue - 1));

        return _factorialCache[inputValue];
    }        
}
```

===========================

Mathematically speaking, this works. One interesting thing is that, if factorial of 5 (for example) is the first value calculated, the cache stores factorial of 2, 3, 4 and 5 (i.e. it stores all the "intermediate" factorials) during this calculation. In my case, there would never be more than one instance of the Foo class alive at the same time, but I decided to declare the dictionary as static in this example to also cover the case in which multiple instances of Foo could exist at the same time.

My questions are:

- Is this the best way to avoid recalculation of factorial for the same values from a technical perspective (e.g. thread safety or similar)?
- Is there any other approach (e.g. something related to lazy evaluation or similar) that would avoid the need of a (static) class-scope variable to store values previously calculated?

All suggestions welcome.

Thanks,

d.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code looks fine but it is not thread safe, as the static [Dictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx) you are using to cache previously calculated values is not thread safe. You need to use proper locking mechanisms when you perform read/write operations on it. Other than that you might find [function Memoization](http://blogs.msdn.com/wesdyer/archive/2007/01/26/function-memoization.aspx) an interesting technique.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks a lot for your answers. Just a quick note to share my findings while investigating your suggestions (I'm not a professional programmer):

So, I checked memoization (a concept I wasn't aware of) but found out that it's not thread-safe "per se" either (i.e. one has to take care of this separately) and, from what I've seen, it has some other implications when implementing it.

So, I decided to continue with my first approach and see if I could make it thread-safe. Luckily enough, I found this "ConcurrentDictionary" in .NET 4.0:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191(VS.100).aspx

[There are other concurrent containers in 4.0 too.]

So, I came up with this modified version, which still relies on a (possibly static) class-scoped field for the cache, but which I think has less implementation constraints and implications than the memoized version:

```
public class Foo
{
    private static ConcurrentDictionary<uint, double> _factorialCache;

    public Foo()
    {            
        if (_factorialCache == null)
            _factorialCache = new ConcurrentDictionary<uint, double>();
    }

    public double Factorial(uint inputValue)
    {
        double returnValue = 0;

        if (inputValue < 2) return 1;

        if (_factorialCache.TryGetValue(inputValue, out returnValue))
            return returnValue;

        returnValue = inputValue * Factorial(inputValue - 1);

        if (!_factorialCache.TryAdd(inputValue, returnValue))
            throw new Exception("Failed to add factorial value to the factorial cache.");

        return returnValue;
    }
}
```

I'm pretty happy with this version now, but any suggestions for improvement are most welcome.

Thanks a lot,

```
d.
```

PS - How do I mark the question as "resolved"?

Comment: Click on the tick near the top left of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for [memoization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization).

There are [many](http://mullr.wordpress.com/2006/05/02/easy-c-memoization/) [different](http://sendhil.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!30862CF919BD131A!1146.entry) [ways](http://www.infoq.com/news/2007/01/CSharp-memory) to achieve this in c#.

Comment: OK.  But which way is optimal for the OP's question?

Comment: Good question... he will have to test all of them if he wants to find the optimal one.

Comment: Point well taken...Sometimes I think we spend too much time on this board worrying about which technique is optimal, approved, preferred, or least fattening.